# Where clause containing date in MySQL statement not working

Tags: mysql, date

Table Name: `DemoTable`.

Total Fields: 2

Fields:

```
id (int, auto increment, primary key)
month_and_year (varchar(10))
```

`month_and_year` contains date as '2015-03', '2015-01', '2014-12' and so on...

I am trying to get values from the table between '2014-10' and '2015-03'.

```
SELECT * FROM DemoTable where month_and_year>='2014-10' AND month_and_year<='2015-03' ORDER BY month_and_year DESC
```

Query does not give desired output as `month_and_year` field has `varchar` data type. Changing varchar to date data type isn't possible as date data type does not accept date in 'yyyy-mm' format.

How can the result be obtained?

PS:Is UNIX_TIMESTAMP() a safe bet in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should never store date value as varchar and choose mysql native date related data types like `date`,`datetime` or `timestamp`

However in your case you need to do some date related calculations before doing the select query. Consider the following table

```
mysql> select * from test ;
+------+----------------+
| id   | month_and_year |
+------+----------------+
|    1 | 2014-10        |
|    2 | 2014-10        |
|    3 | 2014-09        |
|    4 | 2014-11        |
|    5 | 2015-01        |
|    6 | 2014-08        |
+------+----------------+
```

Now the approach would as

First convert the varchar to real date

Then for the lower limit always start the comparison from first day of the year month value

The upper limit will be till the end of the month.

So the query becomes

```
select * from test
where 
date_format(
 str_to_date(
     month_and_year,'%Y-%m'
 ),'%Y-%m-01'
) 
>= 
date_format(
  str_to_date('2014-10','%Y-%m'
  ),'%Y-%m-01'
) 
and 
last_day(
   date_format(
     str_to_date(month_and_year,'%Y-%m'
     ),'%Y-%m-01'
   )
) 
<= 
last_day(
   date_format(
    str_to_date('2015-03','%Y-%m'
    ),'%Y-%m-01'
   )
);
```

The output will be as

```
+------+----------------+
| id   | month_and_year |
+------+----------------+
|    1 | 2014-10        |
|    2 | 2014-10        |
|    4 | 2014-11        |
|    5 | 2015-01        |
+------+----------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the function STR_TO_DATE(string,format);

http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-str_to_date/

Answer (score 0):

You should use either mysql date time [functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html) or use int field in mysql and store `UNIXTIMESTAMP` and compare like you are already doing. I think it is overkill to store unixtimestamp because you only need month and year and you won't benefit a lot from unixtimestamp advantages.

Comment: I don't need to store date as a whole. I just need 'yyyy-mm'. That's why I choose this path. Is there any workaround? UNIX_TIMESTAMP() are unique. So, can't I just pass my date in 'yyyy-mm' format as a parameter & store the resulting time stamp in db. How about that? @RuslanN

Comment: @SajeevC just use mysql datetime format and compare using datetime functions